# Trying to copy an BMP image

Tags: c, image

I'm trying to make a BMP image copy but the image is still breaking and I have no idea what's going on. I need help to solve this problem. After the copy was made, i'll try to do a Steganography by LSB. The image name is "esteganografia.bmp" and the copy "encoded_img.bmp". The image is not compressed.

Header and DIB header infos:
Name: BM
Size: 946746
Offset: 138
Header Size: 124
Width: 710
Height: 444
Color Planes: 1
Bits per pixel: 24
Compression: 0
Image Size: 946608

The code is here:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct bmpheader{
    char name[2];
    unsigned int size;
    int garbage;
    unsigned int offset;
} bmpheader;

typedef struct dibheader{
    unsigned int headersize;
    unsigned int width;
    unsigned int height;
    unsigned short int colorplanes;
    unsigned short int bitsperpixel;
    unsigned int compression;
    unsigned int imagesize;
} dibheader;

typedef struct RGB{
    unsigned char red;
    unsigned char blue;
    unsigned char green;
} RGB;

typedef struct Image{
    int height;
    int width;
    RGB **rgb;
} Image;

int main(){
    FILE *img, *encodedimg;
    bmpheader header;
    dibheader Dheader;
    Image picture;
    int i;
    char mensagem[11];

    //fgets(mensagem, 11, stdin); // recebe a mensagem a ser codificada via terminal.

    // inicio da leitura da imagem.
    img = fopen("esteganografia.bmp", "rb");
    fread(header.name, 2, 1, img);
    fread(&header.size, 3*sizeof(int), 1, img);
    printf("Name: %c%c\nSize: %lu\nOffset: %lu\n", header.name[0], header.name[1], header.size, header.offset);
    fread(&Dheader.headersize, sizeof(dibheader), 1 , img);
    printf("Header Size: %lu\nWidth: %lu\nHeight: %lu\nColor Planes: %u\nBits per pixel: %u\nCompression: %lu\nImage Size: %lu\n", Dheader.headersize, Dheader.width, Dheader.height,Dheader.colorplanes, Dheader.bitsperpixel, Dheader.compression, Dheader.imagesize);
    fseek(img, header.offset, SEEK_SET);
    picture.height = Dheader.height;
    picture.width = Dheader.width;
    picture.rgb = (RGB **) malloc(picture.height*sizeof(RGB*));
    for(i=(picture.height-1); i>=0; i--){
        picture.rgb[i] = (RGB*) malloc(picture.width*sizeof(RGB));
        fread(picture.rgb[i], picture.width, sizeof(RGB), img);
    }
    fclose(img);
    // fim da leitura da imagem.

    // inicio da criação de uma nova img.
    encodedimg = fopen("encoded_img.bmp", "w");
    fwrite(header.name, 2, 1, encodedimg);
    fwrite(&header.size, 3*sizeof(int), 1, encodedimg);
    fwrite(&Dheader.headersize, sizeof(dibheader), 1 , encodedimg);
    for(i=(picture.height-1); i>=0; i--) fwrite(picture.rgb[i], picture.width, sizeof(RGB), encodedimg);
    fclose(encodedimg);
    // fim da criação da nova img.

    printf("%s\n", mensagem);

    for(i=(picture.height-1); i>=0; i--) free(picture.rgb[i]);
    free(picture.rgb);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Make sure to open the output file in binary mode if you're on Windows.

Comment: Open the output file in binary mode: "wb".

Comment: @Shawn: Why only on Windows?

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk: Because on POSIX-compliant operating systems, such as Linux and MacOS, there is no difference between binary mode and text mode.

Comment: That's the only OS that *has* a binary mode. Though it's harmless to add on others.

Comment: (and can serve as a hint to the reader about the files intended purpose)

Comment: Two points `fread(picture.rgb[i], picture.width, sizeof(RGB), img);` has the `size` and `count` arguments reversed (which may not matter), what might matter is that the **stride** of the image may not be the same as its `width * sizeof(RGB)`. The number of bytes in each raster is always a multiple of `4` (perhaps with unused padding). Here, `710 * 3` is `2130` which is not a multiple of `4`, and you should be reading/writing with an array of size `2132` bytes.

Comment: Maybe have to use packed structures, without any padding.